# Loading a Partial view which has a complex model of many sub models into a jquery ui tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, jquery-ui-tabs

I get an error when loading a particular view via an Html.action call to an action and Controller, into a jquery Tab.
The other View is loaded successfully via an HTML.Partial call.
How do I get this other particular partial loaded please.

The tab where the error happens is tab4.
The commented out HTML.Partial call works to a point but when it loads that Partial (User), which has multiple models in it's containing model,..those other models are null and it's iteration over them crashes.
(*That partial is beneath the first block of code.*)
If I try load it from an action Call, then 
the JQuery function ("$#tabs").tabs crashes with ".tabs" is undefined

TIA

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Content via Ajax</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui)
            {
                ui.jqXHR.fail(function ()
                {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Person Detail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Addresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Role Detail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">User Detail</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Index.cshtml")*@
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Address/Index.cshtml")*@
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/IdentityRole/List.cshtml", new List<Catalyst.Shared.IdentityRole>())
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
        @Html.Action("List", "User");

        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/User/List.cshtml", new Catalyst.Mvc.IdentityUserPersonViewModel())*@


    </div>
</div>
```

The Partial which I want to load, but needs data, which I think would work if I called the Action as opposed to calling the Partial.

```
@model Catalyst.Mvc.IdentityUserPersonViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.User = "List";
 }


<div class="panel panel-default" style="width:1400px !important;text-align:center ">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3>Users</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div style="text-align:right;">@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    UserName
                </th>
                <th>
                    Password
                </th>
                <th>
                    Title
                    @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)*@
                </th>
                <th>
                    FirstName
                    @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)*@
                </th>
                <th>
                    LastName
                </th>

                <th>
                    PhoneNumber
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
                <th>
                    Company and Branch
                </th>

                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.identityUsers.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.UserPersons[i].UserPersonId})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.identityUsers[i].UserName)
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.UserPersons[i].UserPersonId})">
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.identityUsers[i].PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", Type = "password" } })
                </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.UserPersons[i].UserPersonId})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.UserPersons[i].Title)
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.UserPersons[i].UserPersonId})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.UserPersons[i].Name)
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.UserPersons[i].UserPersonId})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.UserPersons[i].Surname)
                </a>
            <td>
                @*<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.identityUsers[i].Id})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.identityUsers[i].Email)
                </a>*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @*<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=Model.identityUsers[i].Id})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.identityUsers[i].PhoneNumber)
                </a>*@
            </td>

            <td>
                @*<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" , new {id=item.ID})">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.PhoneNumber)
                </a>*@
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = 
Model.identityUsers[i].Id })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = 
Model.identityUsers[i].Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    </table>

</div>
```

The Controller of the view I can't get laoded

```
   public class UserController : Controller
{
    private IdentityUserBo identityUserBo;
    private PersonBo personBo;
    private IdentityUserPersonBo identityuser_personBo;

    IdentityUserPersonViewModel model = new IdentityUserPersonViewModel();

    public UserController(IdentityUserBo boIdentityUser, PersonBo boPerson, IdentityUserPersonBo boIdentityUserPerson )
    {
        this.identityUserBo = boIdentityUser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("boIdentityUser");
        this.personBo = boPerson ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("boPerson");
        this.identityuser_personBo = boIdentityUserPerson ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("boIdentityUserPerson");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        ExBool result = null;
        IdentityUserPersonViewModel userPersonViewModel = new IdentityUserPersonViewModel();

        result = this.identityUserBo.List(out List<IdentityUser> identityUsers);

        if (!result.Success) throw new Exception(result.Messages);
        if (identityUsers == null) throw new Exception("Could not load IdentityUsers");

        // Ideally see detail eg  branch and tel and email from their respective tables
        userPersonViewModel.identityUsers = identityUsers;

        //Get the Persons, match these via Person.Id -> IdentityUserPerson.FKPersonId + IdentityUserPerson.FKUserId -> IdentityUser.ID
        List<Person> persons = null;
        result = this.personBo.List(out persons);

        //IdentityUserPersonViewModel viewModel = new IdentityUserPersonViewModel();
        userPersonViewModel.persons = persons;

        // Get the IdentityUserPersons 
        List<IdentityUserPerson> identityUserPersons = null;
        result = this.identityuser_personBo.List(out identityUserPersons);

        IdentityUserPerson UPRec = new IdentityUserPerson();
        Person PRec = new Person();
        userPersonViewModel.UserPersons = new List<UserPerson>();

        foreach (IdentityUser rec in userPersonViewModel.identityUsers)
        {
            UPRec = identityUserPersons.Find(x => x.FKUserID == rec.Id);
            if (UPRec != null)
            {
                //UserId, UserPersonId, + Person.Id + Person.Name + Person.Surname
                PRec = persons.Find(y => y.ID == UPRec.FKPersonID);

                UserPerson UsrPers = new UserPerson();
                UsrPers.UserId = rec.Id;
                UsrPers.UserPerson_FKPersonId = UPRec.FKPersonID;
                UsrPers.UserPerson_FKUserId = UPRec.FKUserID;
                UsrPers.Name = PRec.FirstName;
                UsrPers.Surname = PRec.LastName;
                UsrPers.Title = PRec.TitleCode;

                userPersonViewModel.UserPersons.Add(UsrPers);
            }
            else
            {
                UserPerson UsrPers = new UserPerson();
                userPersonViewModel.UserPersons.Add(UsrPers);
            }
        }

        return View(userPersonViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your console what error you got.

and also change this in tab4

```
@{
        @Html.Partial("List", new Catalyst.Mvc.IdentityUserPersonViewModel())
    }
```

Comment: When I specify as per above or any use of Html.Partial,..the action on that partial's controller does not execute, and it's ViewModel is null.
If I specify it with Html.Action, the action does fire,..but then there is no markup generatd into the tab content area.